# Python - Finding all numeric values in a string, then storing each numeric in a list uniquely

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to be able to grab any and all numeric values from a string if found.  Then store them in a list individually.

Currently able to identify all numeric values, but not able to figure out how to store them individually.

```
phones = list()
comment = "Sues phone numbers are P#3774794773 and P#6047947730."

words = comment.split()
for word in words:
    word = word.rstrip()

    nums = re.findall(r'\d{10,10}',word)
    if nums not in phones:
        phones.append(nums)

print(phones)
```

I would like to get those two values to be stored as such.... 3774794773,6047947730.  Instead of a list within a list.

End goal output (print) each value separately.

Current Print: [ [], ['3774794773'], ['6047947730'] ]

Needed Print: 3774794773, 6047947730

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ........... `phones = re.findall(r'\d{10,10}', comment)`

Comment: only want numerics that are a length of 10.   Helps keep program from getting values I would not want such as "10",  "1000", etc

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)',word)`?

Comment: That does help out thank you Wiktor, if more than one is found how can I store those separately?  still would get  [ [], ['3774794773'], ['6047947730'] ].

Comment: What the hell, dude?

Why are you splitting and then matching it to a number?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a double job with the regex (split is also basically regex based) just do the whole thing with a 10 digit number matching regex, like so:

```
comment = "Sues phone numbers are P#3774794773 and P#6047947730."

nums = re.findall(r'\d{10,10}', comment)
print(nums)
```

If you want the numbers also to be exact (not to match longer sequences) you can do the following:

```
comment = "Sues phone numbers are P#3774794773 123145125125215 and P#6047947730."

nums = re.findall(r'\b\d{10,10}\b', comment)
print(nums)
```

(\b is an interesting regex symbol which doesn't really match a part of the string but rather matches "the space between characters" in the string)

both result in:

> ['3774794773', '6047947730']

Answer (score -1):

Save your comment variable in a file and then use this code to separate them into variables

```html
        with open("CS.txt", "r") as f:
            number1,number2 = f.read().split(" ")
            print(number1)
            print(number2)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Wrong question?